# Get entry by language in a module

Tags: craft3, language

I'm trying to get some auto translating done in a craft module. In order to do this I need to get the entry of another language in a save event. Is it possible to get this by language?

```
Event::on(
        Entry::class,
        Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
        function(ModelEvent $event) {
            $entry = $event->sender;
            $isNew = $event->isNew;

            if ($isNew) {
                $enEntry = $entry->getEntryByLanguage('en');
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Event::on(
        Entry::class,
        Entry::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
        function(ModelEvent $event) {
            $entry = $event->sender;
            $isNew = $event->isNew;

            if ($isNew) {
                $enEntry = Entry::find()->id($entry->id)->site('enSiteHandle')->one();
            }
        }
    );
```

Just swap out `enSiteHandle` with your actual English site handle.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. When I try Entry::find()->id($entry->id) I get an object with NULL values.

Comment: You would need to do `Entry::find()->id($entry->id)->one()`

Comment: I get NULL if I do this, so I guess this entry does not exist at this point yet.